# What's the most coin-efficient way to condense pluses onto 1 powerful card?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

Generally you get pluses one at a time, usually on cards you would just sell. Pluses are usually all fed to single powerful card to make it better.

The problem is that that's *expensive*. Feeding a single junky card to an high-level ultimate evo card can cost over 50k coins. What's the most coin-efficient way of moving pluses from a ton of crummy cards to a single powerful card?

Should I feed all the pluses to a junky card for cheap, them feed that one card to the target once it's +297?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the bottom of [this](http://www.puzzledragonx.com/en/article.asp?aid=2) page, there is a formula which lets you calculate the exact fusion costs when plus-eggs are involved.  In addition to the regular cost there is a 1000 coin cost per plus for all the pluses involved.

So we have two parts of the formula we should minimize, the regular cost and the plus-egg cost.  The regular cost is fairly straightforward - just keep your target monster's level low.  Ideally, this means holding on to all your plus-eggs on, as you mentioned, crummy cards with a low max level.

The plus-egg cost is a bit harder to manage.  Since it depends on the total pluses after fusion, you're effectively paying for each plus *every single time* you use it in fusion.  Thus, you want to [feed them as little as possible](http://puzzleanddragonsforum.com/showthread.php?tid=32623) on the way to +297.  There is a table on that page which outlines the cheapest way to +297 as follows:

- Merge your eggs to form a +6 by fusing five +1 eggs to another +1.  Repeat this 48 more times so that you have 49 monsters with +6.  **(1+1+1+1+1+1=6)**
- Merge some of these eggs together to form +36 by fusing five +6 eggs to another +6.  Do this 7 more times so that you have 8 with +36 and one extra +6.  **(6+6+6+6+6+6=36)**
- Feed three +1 eggs to your desired target.
- Make your target have +117 by feeding it three +36 eggs and the last +6.  **(3+36+36+36+6=117)**
- Feed the rest of your +36 eggs to your target.  **(117+36+36+36+36+36=297)**

This results in a total plus-egg cost increase of 999,000 gold.  Of course, you want to make sure that your final +297 has +99 distributed in each stat, or the fusion costs to fix that will make this whole process sort of pointless.

---

It turns out that there is a slightly cheaper (but much more annoying) way to do this.  What I explained above is relatively spot-on, but it turns out there's a better way to get the +117:

- (Create +6 eggs as needed using the method stated above.)
- Make two +24 eggs by fusing **1+1+5+5+6+6=24**.  Create the +5 eggs via fusing five +1 eggs together.
- Make a +26 egg by fusing **1+1+6+6+6+6=26**.
- Make a +31 egg by fusing **1+6+6+6+6+6=31**.
- Finally, merge these together with a few +6 eggs to make your +117. **(6+6+24+24+26+31=117)**

If you really want to save another 10k coins so that your total is 989,000 coins, be my guest.  If you ask me, it's not worth the extra trouble - I just mentioned this here for the sake of completeness.